# mapper_parsing_exception | Elasticsearch | Global Ordinal

Tags: elasticsearch

We were trying to enforce global ordinals on one of the string column which has low cardinality to boost aggregation.

Following is the index description

```
{
  "recharge_olap": {
    "mappings": {
      "recharge_olap": {
        "_all": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "dynamic_templates": [
          {
            "string_fields": {
              "mapping": {
                "index": "not_analyzed",
                "omit_norms": true,
                "type": "string"
              },
              "match": "*",
              "match_mapping_type": "string"
            }
          }
        ],
        "properties": {
          "@version": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "product_brand_name": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "vertical_name": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When we tried to do the global ordinal mapping for product_brand_name, I am getting below error? Is there any documentation that is available somewhere, because I tried to find but couldn't got much help.

```
PUT /recharge_olap/_mapping/recharge_olap
{
  "product_brand_name": {
    "type": "string",
    "doc_values": true,
    "fielddata": {
      "loading" : "eager_global_ordinals" 
    }
  }
}
```

Following is the response.

```
"error": {
          "root_cause": [
             {
                "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
                "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [product_brand_name : {type=string, fielddata={loading=eager_global_ordinals}}]"
             }
          ],
          "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
          "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [product_brand_name : {type=string, fielddata={loading=eager_global_ordinals}}]"
       },
       "status": 400
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the correct command is:

```
PUT /recharge_olap/_mapping/recharge_olap
{
  "properties": {
    "product_brand_name": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed",
      "doc_values": true,
      "fielddata": {
        "loading": "eager_global_ordinals"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: mapping [examples](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html)